# Cooktop warm surface light on dim

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have a new Whirlpool cooktop that has the warm surface light on dim when the cooktop has not been used. It turns on brightly when being used but returns to dim when the surface cools. The service tech could not find anything wrong with it and said it is okay. I'm guessing there is a problem with circuit board that the warm light is mounted on has an issue since the tech ruled out surface switches. Whirlpool is at a loss and do not have their own techs to get this right. Any one see this before?

Comment: While the exact model number would help, I'd suggest to the Whirlpool folks that unless the light being on all the time is documented in their owners manual, that this is a defect and they should replace it. If they won't accept it as a defect, just return it to the place where you bought it, then buy another one.

Comment: As @FreeMan states, this is likely a defect, perhaps due to moisture making a conductive path that keeps a trickle of current in the lamp... and moisture might indicate damage during storage or shipping. Document your complaint to the seller and/or manufacturer in writing.

Comment: I would agree it’s new and not right. I bought a very expensive appliance years back and had the company out to fix it 3 times under warranty. It was a lemon and is in my garage as a backup today. Make them fix it or replace it.

Comment: Whirlpool sent a tech out once already. He stated that he did not find a defect, yet the light was still dimly glowing when he left. He told my wife that he suspects power feedback on a neutral. When he was to come out again he said that he wouldn't expect to find anything since he already looked at it.  He claimed that I would be responsible for the service bill at that point. I told him not to bother coming out then. Since he is the only Whirlpool service tech in my area, Whirlpool authorized him to come out again.

Comment: What I have done to rule out his theory, I tripped all the breakers except the one for the cooktop. Light is still on dim. I did not find any power being induced on the neutral using a digital meter. I wish this tech would bring a control board and not just burners.

Comment: Wce77usohb  The tech came out today. Each control switch was unplugged one at a time and the surface light remained on dim.  I don't know how it wired, but I an wondering if the burners themselves would need to be unplugged . Tech did not have the wiring diagram, but insisted that unplugging the control switches would also isolate the burner. This unit does not have any circuit boards and is still very Flintstone.